# data.table: column name same as variable name

Tags: r, scope, data.table

I'm trying to filter a data.table when a column name is the same as a variable in my environment.

```
dt = data.table(myvar = 1:10)
myvar = 2
dt[myvar %in% myvar]
```

Result:

```
   myvar
 1:     1
 2:     2
 3:     3
 4:     4
 5:     5
 6:     6
 7:     7
 8:     8
 9:     9
10:    10
```

Desired result:

```
   myvar
1:     2
```

Comment: using get() does not appear to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `..varname` method. However, it only works in the `j` (second) argument, not the `i` (first), so while

```r
dt[myvar %in% ..myvar,]
# Error in eval(stub# [[3L]], x, enclos) : object '..myvar' not found
```

fails, you can do

```r
dt[, .SD[myvar %in% ..myvar,]]
#    myvar
#    <int>
# 1:     2
```

---

If you are interested in testing the not-yet-CRAN version of `data.table` (currently 1.14.5), then you can instead use the `env=` feature:

```r
packageVersion("data.table")
# [1] '1.14.5'
dt[ myvar %in% Z, env = list(Z = myvar)]
#    myvar
#    <int>
# 1:     2
```

Comment: Neat. I guess you could also force looking in the global environment - `dt[ myvar %in% globalenv()$myvar,]` - though I don't find that very pretty.

Comment: the not-yet-CRAN dev version of `data.table` has better support with the new `env=` argument, not sure of a timeline

Comment: I was just updating to the dev version again to add `env=` as an answer. I think it's worth flagging. Would it be something like `dt[myvar %in% mv, env=list(mv = myvar)]` ?

Comment: Yeah I saw some answers relating to that, but couldn't quite figure out the syntax they were using.

Comment: @thelatemail yes, exactly, but ... I stole your thunder, sorry, it seemed easiest to add to this.

Comment: All good. I have enough imaginary internet points ;-)

Answer (score 1):

To use `get` and avoid `.SD`, you need to set the environment

```
dt <- data.table::data.table(myvar = 1:10)
myvar <- 2
dt[myvar %in% get("myvar", envir = parent.env(environment()))]
#>    myvar
#> 1:     2
```

Using `parent.env(environment())` instead of `globalenv()` is more stable. Consider its usage in a function where looking in the Global Environment would not work

```
myfun <- function() {
  dt <- data.table::data.table(myvar = 1:10)
  myvar <- 2
  dt[myvar %in% get("myvar", envir = parent.env(environment()))]
}
myfun()
#>    myvar
#> 1:     2
```